# Make a whole line underlined in XSL-FO

Tags: java, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I want to have a whole line underlined in a PDF generated by XSL-FO. I just know how to underline all the text in the line:

```
         <fo:block text-decoration="underline">
                <xsl:value-of select="...."/>
            </fo:block>
```

But I want the line to continue until the right side of the paper, so that someone who prints out the PDF knows that he has to fill in something.
Does anyone know how this is possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved thiss problem by defining a border at the end of the block:

```
      <fo:block border-after-style="solid">
           <xsl:value-of select="...."/>
      </fo:block>
```